# Is there an option to plot the Z axis reversed (as shown in the figure)?

Tags: graphics, plotting

Normally the Z axis is plotted from bottom-to-top as shown below :
[image: normal z-axis running bottom-to-top]

I got a plot with the axis (**axes** to be more precise) reversed as shown below:[image]

Is there a way to **force the axes to be plotted top-to-bottom**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Mathematica* graphics is interactive. Just drag & rotate the plot with mouse till you flip it up side down. You also can do this programmatically:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x y]^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ViewPoint -> {-1, -2.5, -1}, 
ViewVertical -> {0, 0, -1}]
```

[image]

Here is how I got these options - if you are curious. Produce *Mathematica* 3D graphics object and play with it by rotating it around. As soon as you like its orientation excute

```
Options[%]
```

And get something like this:

```
Out[2] = {Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.4},  Method -> 
{"RotationControl" -> "Globe"}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {0., 1.}}, 
PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]},  
ViewPoint -> {-1, -2.5, -1}, ViewVertical -> {0, 0, -1}}
```

Options `ViewPoint` and `ViewVertical` will be most important for your particular case. You can use them now in your code to avoid the need to adjust graphics interactively every time.

**NOTE (thanks to @Heike comment below):**

In some cases if `Options[%]` does not work you may try this:

[image]

which will produce the set of options I showed above.

Comment: Well, that's a boring solution. :-)

Comment: @BrettChampion I'd be happy to see someone cooking something more entertaining ;-)

Comment: The values for `ViewPoint` and `ViewVertical` aren't updated on my system when I evaluate `Options[%]` after rotating the plot. The only way I can get the updated values is to wrap `Options[]` directly around the actual plot, rotate the plot, and re-evaluate the whole expression.

Comment: @Heike I'm running M. V8.0.4 on Win7 - works for me. What is your system?

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov I'm using v8.0.4 on OS X.

Comment: @Heike Duly noted ;-) - post updated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using `ScalingFunctions`

```
Plot3D[Sin[x y]^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
 ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, Identity, "Reverse"}]
```

[image]